# Find highest/lowest value in matrix

Tags: matlab

very basic question: How can I find the highest or lowest value in a random matrix.
I know there is a possibility to say:

```
a = find(A>0.5)
```

but what I'm looking for would be more like this:

```
A = rand(5,5)
A = 
0.9388    0.9498    0.6059    0.7447    0.2835
0.6338    0.0104    0.5179    0.8738    0.0586
0.9297    0.1678    0.9429    0.9641    0.8210
0.0629    0.7553    0.7412    0.9819    0.1795
0.3069    0.8338    0.7011    0.9186    0.0349

% find highest (or lowest) value

ans = A(19)%for the highest or A(7) %for the lowest value in this case
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at the [`min()`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/min.html) and `max()` functions. They can return both the highest/lowest value, and its index:

```
[B,I]=min(A(:)); %# note I fixed a bug on this line!
```

returns `I=7` and `B=A(7)=A(2,2)`. The expression `A(:)` tells MATLAB to treat A as a 1D array for now, so even though A is 5x5, it returns the linear index 7.

If you need the 2D coordinates, i.e. the "2,2" in `B=A(7)=A(2,2)`, you can use `[I,J] = ind2sub(size(A),I)` which returns `I=2,J=2`, see [here](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/ind2sub.html).

*Update*
If you need all the entries' indices which reach the minimum value, you can use [find](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/find.html):

```
I = find(A==min(A(:));
```

`I` is now a vector of all of them.

Comment: it is not really precise as I hoped! If I write [B,I]=min(min(A)), I'll get its smallest value as "B" and its row position ("I"), BUT I'll have no idea which column it belongs to. :(

Comment: @kojikurac: Sorry, my code had a bug - I fixed it now. Don't use min(min(A)), use min(A(:)) instead.

Comment: ok, this is much better, I still have only one problem. In case I have 2 or more identical numbers, it will always choose only the first one. Is there any way to make it present ALL of them?

Comment: vielen lieben Dank! I'm no mathematician (it's pretty obvious, isn't it).

Comment: @kojikurac If you want to find easily in which column your minimum is located, use [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) afterwards

Answer (score 3):

For matrices you need to run the [MIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/min.html) and [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) functions twice since they operate column-wise, i.e. `max(A)` returns a vector with each element being the maximum element in the corresponding column of A.

```
>> A = rand(4)

A =

         0.421761282626275         0.655740699156587         0.678735154857773         0.655477890177557
         0.915735525189067        0.0357116785741896         0.757740130578333         0.171186687811562
         0.792207329559554         0.849129305868777         0.743132468124916         0.706046088019609
         0.959492426392903         0.933993247757551         0.392227019534168        0.0318328463774207

>> max(max(A))

ans =

         0.959492426392903

>> min(min(A))

ans =

        0.0318328463774207
```

Note that this only works for matrices. Higher dimensional arrays would require running MIN and MAX as many times as there are dimensions which you can get using [NDIMS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ndims.html).

Comment: Instead of `min(min(A))` you can use `min(A(:))` which works no matter how many dimensions `A` has.

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg - Yes! Great tip! Thanks for that...forgot that A(:) serializes the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
A=magic(5)
[x,y]=find(A==max(max(A))) %index maximum of the matrix A 
A_max=A(x,y)
[x1,y1]=find(A==min(max(A))) %index minimum of the matrix A 
A_min=A(x1,y1)
```